# Creating procedurally generated nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation, loops, tikz-matrix

I am relatively new to Ti*k*Z, and have been hacking together figures as I need them for uni assignments from various examples on the internet.

Now I am moving into research, I am having to write a lot more and produce many more and complex figures and I thought it was probably time to learn how to do things properly.

Here is an example of the sorts of figures that I am wanting to produce:

[image: partitioned network]

There are lots of nodes and lots of connections between them all.

I am able to reproduce this figure using Ti*k*Z by individually placing every node and then individually creating a connection for each, however this is extremely time consuming and there are even larger figures I need to create with many more connections which will be even more time consuming.

I was wondering what were the smarter ways to go about producing large figures with many features, but which are structurally quite simple (to use an example, large matrix of nodes with connections running from each node in a column to each node in the next column)?

In some things I have seen people use a matrix for positioning of nodes, and also that it is possible to use for loops and if statements in Ti*k*Z as well, however the prospect of having to delve into and try to understand the entire language of Ti*k*Z myself is a bit daunting on top of the other work I am trying to do - so if anyone knows of any good examples or resources that would give some good high-level information about the kinds of techniques that would be useful for my purposes, or even just some tips on where to start, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarise yourself further with our format. I think the best thing to read is chapter 19 of the [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual (page 258).

Comment: And chapter 83 which is about loops. (You don't have to have read the 82 chapters which come before it to follow it.)

Comment: I'd use Python or another scripting language to generate the code.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i will have a look at the relevant chapters, and @UweZiegenhagen: i didnt think of generating the code with a scripting language, thats a good idea too - thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although using multiple `\foreach` loops does make the "semantic" layout of the network a little unclear, it certainly makes its creation easier. I have taken some liberties with the required connections otherwise the network starts to look a bit cluttered.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Triangle,
   cell/.style={circle, draw},
   connection/.style={shorten >=.125cm, shorten <=.125cm},
]

\foreach \i in {1,...,8}
  \foreach \x [count=\j] in {1,2,5,6,7}
    \node [cell] (cell-\i-\j) at (\x*1.5, \i) {};

\node [cell, draw=none, below=1cm] (cell')  at ($(cell-1-4)!0.5!(cell-1-5)$) {};
\node [cell, draw=none, above=1cm] (cell'') at ($(cell-8-4)!0.5!(cell-8-5)$) {};

\foreach \i in {1,...,8}{
  \foreach \j in {1,3} \draw [->] (cell-\i-\j)++(-1,0) -- (cell-\i-\j);
  \foreach \j in {2,5} \draw [<-] (cell-\i-\j)++(1,0) -- (cell-\i-\j);
}

\foreach \m/\n/\o/\p in {1/4/1/2,5/8/1/2, 3/6/1/2, 1/4/3/4, 5/8/3/4, 3/6/4/5}
  \foreach \i in {\m,...,\n}
    \foreach \j in {\m,...,\n} \draw [connection] (cell-\i-\o) -- (cell-\j-\p);

\foreach \m/\n/\q in {1/2/', 7/8/''}
  \foreach \i in {\m,\n}{
    \draw [connection] (cell-\i-4) -- (cell-\i-5);
    \foreach \j in {4,5} \draw [connection] (cell\q) -- (cell-\i-\j);
  }

\coordinate (@')  at ($(cell') +(5/4,-1/2)$);
\coordinate (@'') at ($(cell'')+(5/4, 1/2)$);
\draw [<->] (cell'.center) |- (@') -- (@'') -| (cell''.center);

\node [above left=.5cm]  at (cell-8-1) {in};
\node [above right=.5cm] at (cell-8-2) {out};

\node [above left=.5cm]  at (cell-8-3) {in};
\node [above right=.5cm] at (cell-8-5) {out};

\draw [Implies-Implies, double, thick, double distance=5pt, 
  shorten >=1.25cm, shorten <=1.25cm] 
  ($(cell-4-2)!0.5!(cell-5-2)$) -- ($(cell-4-3)!0.5!(cell-5-3)$)
  node [midway, above=1cm, font=\large] {?};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much, i think i will be able to follow this and pull it apart to make the other figures that i need, thanks again.